# Make lists from elements of JSON file

Tags: python, json

I would like to make three different lists out of a JSON file (https://www.dropbox.com/s/woxtqy634g89f0r/tags.json?dl=0) say, A, B, and C:

```
A: (13,13,...,37)
B: (12,14,...,32)
C: ([-1.3875, 1.3875, -1.95 ], [[-2.775, -0., -0., ], .., [-0., 2.775, -0. ]])
```

Is there any quick and smart way to do it?

I tried in jupyter-notebook:

```
with open('tags.json', 'r') as f:
    tags = json.load(f)
tags['neb.00']
```

the output would give me

> '13->12 0.2906332796567428 [-1.3875  1.3875 -1.95  ]'

And then I can do something like `tags['neb.03'][0:2]` to get `13` and so on. But this is not a good way of doing and I hope there is a proper way to do it. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: "this is not a good way of doing" Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for k,v in data.items():
    A =v[:v.index('-')]
    B =v[v.index('>')+1:v.index('[')]
    C =v[v.index('[')::]
    print(k,A,B,C)
```

.items() iterates through dict keys(k) and values(v)

i don't know if that's the answer you were looking for but looking at your data, it seems like it has a stable structure. i guess you can append each value to a list.

Comment: Thanks @FMARAD. That's exactly I was looking for. It solved my problem!

Comment: Hi, actually I realized there is a tiny bit of thing still left. If you look at 'C' in the main question, it's actually a list but what I am getting is a string obvioisuly like [-1.3875  1.3875 -1.95  ] but I want [-1.3875,  1.3875, -1.95  ]. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: C.strip("[]").split(",")

Comment: Somehow that didn't work for me. It only changed from [-1.3875 1.3875 -1.95 ] to ['-1.3875  1.3875 -1.95  '].

Comment: so i just got on my PC, C.
strip("[]").split() but this would give you list of strings, i guess you can manipulate that.

Comment: Ok, no problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json
import re

with open('tags.json', 'r') as f:
    tags = json.load(f)

A = []
B = []
C = []
for x in sorted(tags.keys()):
    m = re.search(r'(\d+)->(\d+) (\d+\.\d+) \[(.+)\]', tags[x])
    if not m:
        print("Not matching:", tags[x])
        continue
    A.append(int(m.group(1)))
    B.append(int(m.group(2)))
    C.append([float(y) for y in m.group(4).split()])
```

sorted() or other functions if you need your items ordered in a deterministic way.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Giving me: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: That means the regex did not match. Your input is probably more complex than the example you posted. Edited to skip non-matching pattern so that you can refine the regex.